# Create a function to save multiple ggplots in named folders based on two input variables with different lengths

Tags: r, subset, sapply, mapply, ggsave

I have a function to save multiple ggplots from different models such as the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(marginaleffects)

outcome_var_list = c("mpg","cyl","wt","hp")
interact_var_list =  c("gear","am","wt")

model_ <- function(k){
  
  outcome_var_list = outcome_var_list[outcome_var_list == k] 
  
  results = list()
  for (r in interact_var_list) {
    f = paste(k, "~", r, "*factor(vs)")
    m = lm(f, subset(mtcars, carb %in% c(1,2,3,4)))
    s = plot_slopes(m, variables = r, condition = "vs", draw = FALSE)
    tmp = s[, c("estimate", "conf.low", "conf.high", "vs")]
    tmp$outcome = k
    tmp$regressor = r
    results = c(results, list(tmp))
  }
  results = do.call("rbind", results)  
  
  
  plot1 = results %>% mutate(min = min(conf.low), max = max(conf.high)) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=factor(vs), y=estimate, color = regressor, ymin=conf.low, ymax=conf.high)) + 
    geom_errorbar(position = position_dodge(0.4)) + geom_point(position = position_dodge(0.4))
  
  ggsave(plot1,file=paste0("plot_",k,".png"),path="folder1/subfolder")
  
}

safe_model <- safely(model_)
iterate <- sapply(outcome_var_list,safe_model)
```

I now want to repeat this for multiple subsets of the data. I therefore attempt to map two variables to the function (now `mapply` instead of `sapply`) to take subsets of `mtcars` and produce plots in different subfolders named for the subset variable. The new code looks like the following:

```
outcome_var_list = c("mpg","cyl","wt","hp")
interact_var_list =  c("gear","am","wt")
subset_list = unique(mtcars$disp)

model_ <- function(k,c){
  
mtcars = mtcars[mtcars$disp == c,]
  
  
  outcome_var_list = outcome_var_list[outcome_var_list == k] 
  
  results = list()
  for (r in interact_var_list) {
    f = paste(k, "~", r, "*factor(vs)")
    m = lm(f, subset(mtcars, carb %in% c(1,2,3,4)))
    s = plot_slopes(m, variables = r, condition = "vs", draw = FALSE)
    tmp = s[, c("estimate", "conf.low", "conf.high", "vs")]
    tmp$outcome = k
    tmp$regressor = r
    results = c(results, list(tmp))
  }
  results = do.call("rbind", results)  
  
  
  plot1 = results %>% mutate(min = min(conf.low), max = max(conf.high)) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=factor(vs), y=estimate, color = regressor, ymin=conf.low, ymax=conf.high)) + 
    geom_errorbar(position = position_dodge(0.4)) + geom_point(position = position_dodge(0.4))
  
  ggsave(plot1,file=paste0("plot_",k,".png"),path = paste0("folder1/",c))
  
}

safe_model <- safely(model_)
iterate <- mapply(safe_model,outcome_var_list,subset_list)
```

Unfortunately, I receive the following warning, and no plots are generated: `warning: longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter`

How can I map the function to different subsets and repeat exactly what I did for the entire `mtcars` dataset, but instead with subsets and creating new subfolders? I know that my input variables have different lengths, but I want every combination to be generated. So for each value of outcome_var_list, there should be 1 plot for disp == 160, 1 for disp == 108, etc.

Comment: You get the same error with `mapply(sum, 1:3, 1:2)` The problem is that when you use `mapply`, to iterate over multiple vectors, those vectors need to be the same length. It's unclear exactly what combinations you want otherwise. Do you want all possible combinations of `outcome_var_list` and `subset_list`? If so, you need to create such a list with `expand.grid` or other such function.

Comment: Yes @MrFlick that is exactly what I would need. Every combination of outcome_var_list and subset_list. But how do I put that into mapply then? Or do I use a different function?

Comment: You can get every combination with `expand.grid(outcome_var_list, subset_list)` and then pass those two columns to `mapply`. With this example you still get an error that says "contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels" for every subset

Comment: Brilliant, that works! I tried it with my actual data and that does the trick. There's just not sufficient variation in this replication data. Thank you so much!